# Firestore returning an empty array when there are objects at the specified path

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ListVM()
    @FirestoreQuery var items: [Item]
    
    init(userId: String) {
        self._items = FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "/users/\(userId)/items")
        print(items)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Colors.PRIMARY
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundStyle(Colors.WHITE)
                            .font(.title)
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            viewModel.showingNewItemView = true
                        } label: {
                            Label("", systemImage: "plus")
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundStyle(Colors.WHITE)
                                .controlSize(.extraLarge)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    List(items) { item in
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showingNewItemView, content: {
                NewItemView(showingNewItemView: $viewModel.showingNewItemView)
            })
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListView(userId: "OWD1UmcgSqMDLHwZIlqlVrxoYsn1")
}
```

[image: What I see in the database.]

[image: Inside the items collection.]

I was expecting Firebase to return Item objects, which I know have a title property. I also know that the items collection holds Item objects. I'm pretty new to working with Firebase but I'm assuming that since auth functionality works, the problem must be in this file.

I haven't tried a bunch because I have no idea what the problem could be. The print statement in init prints an empty array.

Comment: Maybe the empty array means there is no data coming back from the query, because there are no matching documents?  We can't see the locations of the query (because we can't see userId) and we can't see the contents of the database at that location.  You should edit the question to show enough information that anyone can use the duplicate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirestoreQuery` does not have error handling in its simplest form

```
@FirestoreQuery var items: [Item]
```

You can use

```
@FirestoreQuery var result: Result<[Item], Error>
```

And your `body` would need a `switch`

```
var body: some View {
    switch result {
    case .success(let items):
        Text(items.count, format: .number) //Put your List here
    case .failure(let error):
        Text(error.localizedDescription) //Error View
            .task {
                print(error) //Print more detailed error to console.
            }
    }
}
```

More often than not you have some element that is missing a field that is not marked as `Optional` this will help you get a better error. But more often than not just add a `?` to the variable mentioned in the `error`.

Comment: Hi, so that worked. This is what I got: `codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "dueDate", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil)` It's in reference to the dueDate property, which is a swift Date object.

Comment: @garrett that basically says we expected a “Type” but for a “Number” so in your Model. Date does decode to a Number usually unless there is some kind of strategy. Idk if Firebase add a strategy by default so you you can try is change Date to Double as a test.

Comment: Looking into changing it to and from a TimeInterval, but I'll probably just change all logic to TimeInterval.

Comment: @Garrett Firebase also has a Timestamp type that works with Date.